# replace tag content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my html I have this code:

```
<div class="selfclear">
      <h3><a id="lnkName" href="/dir/subdir/?id=577">Name</a></h3>
       <address>
                       Street name, 3  <br />3222 City<br />Phone. : 0202 777 876 
        </address>
</div>
```

I want to replace the phone number depending on the id passed to the url within the  tag using Jquery.

So far I was able to get the id  doing so:

```
function getID(){
    var a = $('#lnkName').attr('href').split('=');
    var id= a[1];
}
```

and the content of  with :

```
function print_Address(){
    var div = $('#lnkName');
    if (!div.length) return;
    var adress = $('#lnkName').parent().siblings('address').html();
    adress.replace( '/Phone : .*/', '/Phone : 777' );
    var newtel = $('#lnkName').parent().siblings('address').html( adress );
        div.html(newtel).show('slow',function(){
          });
}
```

The problem is with replacing function as the print_Address() just print me the content of address but does not load the new content

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't wrap the phone number in its own tag, e.g. `<span id="phone">`? This makes the whole process much, much simpler.

Comment: Agree with the above, much simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you would like to replace 777 with the id number from the href?

If so can you not just do the following?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var a = $('#lnkName').attr('href').split('=');
        var id= a[1];
        $('#phone-number').text(id);
    });
</script>
<div class="selfclear">
    <h3><a id="lnkName" href="/dir/subdir/?id=577">Name</a></h3>
    <address>Street name, 3  <br />3222 City<br />Phone. : 0202 <span id="phone-number">777</span> 876</address>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First order of business:  Stop looking up the same things over and over again.

```
var div = $('#lnkName');

if (!div.length) return;

var address = div.parent().siblings('address');
var addressText = address.html();
addressText.replace( '/Phone : .*/', '/Phone : 777' );
address.html( addressText ).show('slow', function(){});
```

Second, I don't think your Regexp is matching what you wanted to match.  Notice that your original text says "Phone. :"  Just stick the phone number into a span or div with a class.  It'll help you here, but it'll help even more if/when you get around to testing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with the this line:

```
adress.replace( '/Phone : .*/', '/Phone : 777' )
```

1. there is a dot left after 'Phone' in your html
2. the string to be replace should not be prefixed with backslash '/'.

Check the workable demo at http://jsfiddle.net/YwgWP/

Comment: thanks your code works great but my friend just changed his html code for:<div class="selfclear">
      <h4>Name</h4>
       <address>
                       Street name, 3  <br />3222 City<br />Phone. : 0202 777 876 
        </address>
</div> and passed the id thru the url I could get the get vars but $('#lnkName').parent().siblings('address').html( adress ); doesnt work anymore... any idea?